# Send Curl Request Java

Tags: java, android, curl, ibm-watson, watson

how can i send this curl post request using java.

```
curl -X POST -F "beagle_positive_examples=@beagle.zip" -F "husky_positive_examples=@husky.zip" -F "goldenretriever_positive_examples=@golden-retriever.zip" -F "negative_examples=@cats.zip" -F "name=dogs" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classifiers?api_key={api-key}&version=2016-05-20"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the API reference for check how to use Custom Classifier inside Visual Recognition Service with Java. Check [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v3/#classifiers).

Maybe you're looking for it:

```
public ServiceCall createClassifier(CreateClassifierOptions options) {
    Validator.notNull(options, " options cannot be null");

    Builder bodyBuilder = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
    bodyBuilder.addFormDataPart(PARAM_NAME, options.classifierName());

    // Classes
    for (String className : options.classNames()) {
      String dataName = className + "_" + PARAM_POSITIVE_EXAMPLES;
      RequestBody requestBody =
          RequestBody.create(HttpMediaType.BINARY_FILE, options.positiveExamplesByClassName(className));
      bodyBuilder.addFormDataPart(dataName, options.positiveExamplesByClassName(className).getName(), requestBody);
    }

    if (options.negativeExamples() != null) {
      RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(HttpMediaType.BINARY_FILE, options.negativeExamples());
      bodyBuilder.addFormDataPart(PARAM_NEGATIVE_EXAMPLES, options.negativeExamples().getName(), requestBody);
    }

    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = RequestBuilder.post(PATH_CLASSIFIERS);
    requestBuilder.query(VERSION, versionDate).body(bodyBuilder.build());

    return createServiceCall(requestBuilder.build(), ResponseConverterUtils.getObject(VisualClassifier.class));
  }
```

This link has Official examples of using this API from IBM Developers. And this code shows how to use custom classifiers, and if you want to know the parameters that you can use, check the reference link.

Remember: Negative example files should contain images that *do not depict the subject* of any of the positive examples.